# Tomcat 8.5 WEB-INF content accessible URL

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am having a security issue with tomcat 8.5 application WEB-INF contents.  I am not suppose to able to access content of WEB-INF (i.e. web.xml)via url but I can seem to access.  How do I restrict this access?  I thought it should be restricted out the box.  I am using linux and the permission is rw for user and r for group.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: are you really using tomcat? tomcat should disable the access by default.

Comment: Weird. Tomcat should not allow you to access WEB-INF content (regardless of the file system permissions). You might want to set up your web app in a fresh tomcat and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, files under /WEB-INF are not accessible directly from outside. If the files can be accessible, your application has vulnerabilities, like path traversal. A simple solution is, for example, to restrict the access to URLs including WEB-INF by Apache in front of Tomcat.